# express() or new express()

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am really confused about the statement `var app = express()`. I was going through  some old post about this(on stackoverflow) and some guy said, var app = express() is similar to var app = new express(). I have 2 js file to simulate this, but I cant understand how does 'new express()' get the desired result.

```
//play.js
  var express = require('./express');
   var app = new express();
 // this will call createApplication function as app is referencing to it.
   console.log(app); // "app"
```

and

```
//express.js
function createApplication(){
   var app = 'app';
    return app;
  }
module.exports = createApplication;
```

When I use var app = new express(), the result is `createApplication {}`
and not `app`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`express` is a factory function, not a constructor function.  It should be called like an normal function, not used with `new`.

You can see the code for it right here: https://github.com/expressjs/express/blob/master/lib/express.js#L37

```
function createApplication() {
  var app = function(req, res, next) {
    app.handle(req, res, next);
  };

  mixin(app, EventEmitter.prototype, false);
  mixin(app, proto, false);

  // expose the prototype that will get set on requests
  app.request = Object.create(req, {
    app: { configurable: true, enumerable: true, writable: true, value: app }
  })

  // expose the prototype that will get set on responses
  app.response = Object.create(res, {
    app: { configurable: true, enumerable: true, writable: true, value: app }
  })

  app.init();
  return app;
}
```

It is this `createApplication()` function that is exports from `require('./express');` so when you call `express()`, you're just calling this `createApplication()` function.

---

It may happen to work by doing `new express()` because the `createApplication()` function will also be called (as a constructor) in that case and since it returns the `app` object that will be the result of `new express()`, but that is a wasteful way to do it because the `new` operator will create an object that will then be thrown away.

Comment: express aside, if I just use these dummy js files, when I use var app = new express() , what did I do to get the result `createApplication {}` , and if I want to get the result as just `app`, how do I do that (with using the new keyword).

Comment: @RohanSharma - Why do insist on trying to use `new express()`?  That's NOT how it was designed to be used.  It probably happens to work if you do `const app = new express()`, but that is NOT how it was designed to be used.

Comment: okay, I am just trying to understand the logic, I am not experienced much in programming, I understand that we are exporting a function and using a function when we use var = express(), i guess ill try to hit and try and learn whats going on

Comment: @RohanSharma - When you call `express()`, it calls the exported function `createApplication()` shown in my answer.  Executing that function creates another function (which is an object in Javascript), assigns a bunch of properties to that function object, gives it a prototype and then returns that new object. I don't know why Express does it this way rather than using a normal constructor with `new`.  It's just a different and more manual way of creating a new object that has a prototype and some methods.